# Why can we get eigenvalue through solving $det(A-\lambda I)=0$?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In many notes, I see

$A\vec{v}=\lambda \vec{v}$

$(A-\lambda)\vec{v}=\vec{0}$

$det(A-\lambda I)=0$

How to get line 3 actually?

Thanks.

Comment: If $A - \lambda I$ has a nontrivial kernel, it is not invertible, hence its determinant is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your system of linear equations has a *non-trivial* solution, then the matrix of this system must be degenerate, i.e. it's det is $0$. The main point is that the vector $v$ in the first line of your question is *non-zero*.

Comment: Can you explain "degenerate" a bit?